# Is it possible to generate a random vector space in Mathematica?

Tags: vector, vector-calculus

The idea is that I’d like to try to use Mathematica to work through proofs. So if a proof says, “Let there be a vector space V…”, I would like to see a concrete representation of that vector space in Mathematica for me to automate some aspects of calculation I might do manually. Whatever the next step in the proof is, I’d like to try to do this in Mathematica too. For example, it might say to take the product of V and some set A. I would then like to take that product in Mathematica to produce the new mathematical object. Along the way I could examine the objects in detail with methods from Mathematica. Maybe it can print out key information or visualisation about a certain object for me to get a better idea of its specific structure or details.

To do this, I think it could be cool if I could just pick a vector space at random from the class of all possible vector spaces.

If that’s not possible, I could focus on a specific type of vector space, if those are easier to randomly generate.

I’m new to Mathematica so I haven’t tried anything yet because this is how I want to get started.

Comment: What do you mean by 'vector space' ? It's a very abstract mathematical concept - you have spaces of matrices, functions, higher order tensors,  etc. they're all examples of vector spaces And if you mean random Euclidean vectors, which field?, which dimension? Do you want a random basis? Should it be orthonormal or not? So many details missing from your question.

Comment: It also would be helpful to know what you already have tried.

Comment: FWIW, it sounds a bit like the geometric scene functionality, except for vector spaces instead of geometry.  The geometry stuff looks like a big project. I expect this would be, too, unless someone has done it.